# Cannot update a field in Django Rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have to update this 'completed' field in Rest API whenever required. when i go to the url, it is showing a createView but not update view. Also update is not working. How chould i change only 'completed' field to wither True or False whenever i requested a particular Url

**serializers.py**

```
class ToDoModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Todo
        fields = [
            'content',
            'completed',

            ]
```

**models.py**

```
class Todo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['timestamp']
```

**views.py**

```
class UpdateCompleted(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Todo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ToDoModelSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        instance.name = request.data.get("completed")
        instance.save()

        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.TodoListApiView.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('<int:pk>/toggle/', views.UpdateCompleted.as_view(), name='update'),
    path('completed/', views.TodoListCompletedApiView.as_view(), name='completed'),
    path('create/', views.TodoCreateApiView.as_view(), name='create'),
]
```

Comment: "when I go to the url", which url? Please explain exactly what data you are submitting to which url and what is happening (i.e. what is the response). "it is showing createView" doesn't make sense, what does that mean when you're calling an API? Always be specific, e.g. show us the entire POST request you're submitting (the json, the url) and show us the entire response you get (the json).

Comment: I have added urls.py. Whenever i go to update url, i have to update the completed field which is not working

Comment: Please be specific. Tell us which url you "go to" (/something/else/whatever). Tell us if you use GET or POST. If it's a POST, show us the json data you're submitting. Show us the json data you get in the response.

Comment: Also your `update()` method doesn't make sense. Remove it, the default `update` method of the generic `UpdateAPIView` already does what you want. I don't understand what `instance.name` is (your model doesn't have a name attribute).

Comment: Im a beggineer. Whenever i go to /<pk>/toggle it should edit that object's completed field to either True or False. How should i do that?

Comment: What do you mean "go to /<pk>/toggle". How do you "go" to it?

Comment: using ajax GET method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203594/discussion-between-dirkgroten-and-maharshi-bingumalla).